# C# Automapper on the nested list

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

I've the following dtos and I'm trying to use automapper, but couldn't quite understand on how to do the same, as this is the first time I'm using automapper any help is really appreciated

```
string order {get;set;}
string orderType {get;set;}
List<OrderItem> Items {get;set;}
}

public class OrderItem{
string itemID {get;set;}
Price price {get;set;}
}

public class Price {
string total {get;set;}
string regular {get;set;}
}

public class request {
string order {get;set;}
string orderType {get;set;}
List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Item {
string itemID {get;set;}
string itemPrice {get;set;}
string regularPrice {get;set;}
}


I'm trying the following

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<request,requestDTO>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.order, act=>act.MapFrom(src => src.order))
.ForMember(dest => dest.orderType, act=>act.MapFrom(src => src.orderType))
})

How do I create mapping to map 

**
src.item.itemID to dest.item.itemID
src.item.itemPrice to dest.item.price.total
src.item.regularPrice to dest.item.price.regular**

for all the items in my source array
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create another map for `Item` and `OrderItem` as follows:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Item, OrderItem>()
.ForPath(dest => dest.price.total, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.itemPrice))
.ForPath(dest => dest.price.regular, act =>act.MapFrom(src => src.item.regularPrice));
```

Also note that the mapper `<request,requestDTO>` does not need any explicit `ForMember` call, as both objects have identical property names:

```
cfg.CreateMap<request,requestDTO>();
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. I'll try this out.

Comment: how do I iterate through the list in this case ?

Comment: Collection mapping are handled by AM. If you create a map from `Item` to `OrderItem`, Automapper knows how to map `List<Item>` to `List<OrderItem>`